# Is there any tool to silent Os Install

Tags: linux, operating-system, installer

I need to Install fedora 25 in 10+ system. My intention to **Install Os with slight installation instead of click next and next** like [packer](https://github.com/lwieske/packer-windows2016-standard).

But packer only setup vagrant environment. I need to Setup fresh system.

Suggest me, **any tool is out there to install Os with slight instead of click next and next.**

Comment: Are all affected computers identical in hardware (same CPU, disk size, etc)? And is it acceptable that in the end the "first user" on them is identical, too? If so, and it's acceptable to do the "click-through" install once: Do a partition backup afterwards and restore that to the other machines, booted from a LiveCD. The tool for that would be `partimage`. Would that suit your needs?

Comment: CloneZilla?....

Comment: @lzzy we have different system configurations, so we need another options

Comment: @lzzy@Headcrab what about cobbler https://github.com/cobbler/cobbler